# Problem with updating LazyVerticalGrid in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have a problem with showing and updating data in LazyVerticalGrid.
The idea is to show the initial list (with default list) and when I receive some data to arraylistListFlow, linkedListListFlow or copyOnWriteArrayListFlow update that LazyVerticalGrid with new data. But when I go to this page (where the list should be shown) I see a default list for like 1 sec and that's it. It gets overwritten by an empty list I think or something.
How do I achieve the behaviour when I open a screen, I see this  LazyVerticalGrid with default list and when data comes to arraylistListFlow, linkedListListFlow or copyOnWriteArrayListFlow the list gets updated.

Very important when the data arrives to show all 3 lists (arraylistListFlow, linkedListListFlow and copyOnWriteArrayListFlow) at the same time. Each next list shouldn't overwrite the previous one.

Do you have an idea how to do it? Please help.

```
        val initialList: List<PerformanceResultModel> = Utils.initList

        val arraylistListState by viewModel.arraylistListFlow.collectAsState(initial = Utils.initList)
        val linkedListListState by viewModel.linkedListListFlow.collectAsState(initial = Utils.initList)
        val copyOnWriteArrayListState by viewModel.copyOnWriteArrayListFlow.collectAsState(initial = Utils.initList)

        val combinedList = (arraylistListState + linkedListListState + copyOnWriteArrayListState).distinct()
        var currentList by remember { mutableStateOf(initialList) }

       LaunchedEffect(combinedList) {
            currentList = combinedList
        }

        if (initialList.isNotEmpty()) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(top = 10.dp)
            ) {
                items(initialList.size) { index ->
                    val performanceResult = initialList[index]
                    RecyclerViewItem(performanceResult)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the problem. I forgot to initialize StateFlows...

[image]